# Disable javascript toggle after end date is selected (Wordpress/Woocommerce)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am working on a website which involves room bookings. I am using the Woocommerce Bookings Plugin: https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/

Demo of the problem: http://riado.christophvh.be/en/rooms/alaouite-room/

On a specific room I show a calendar, you need to pick a start & end date of your stay, which all works like it should. Above the calendar it shows the text: "Choose start date", when you click a start date it switches to : "Choose end date".

**Question**

When you selected both your start date & end date, the label above the calendar will show 'Choose start date' again, which can be very confusing for a customer. I am assuming this label is a toggle triggered with javascript. So what I need to do is either hide this message after both dates are selected or show a other message. How would I accomplish that?

Javascript code I found of this in the plugin folder:

```
select_date_trigger: function( date ) {
    var fieldset          = $( this ).closest('fieldset');
    var picker            = fieldset.find( '.picker:eq(0)' );
    var form              = $( this ).closest( 'form' );
    var parsed_date       = date.split( '-' );
    var start_or_end_date = picker.data( 'start_or_end_date' );
    if ( ! picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) || ! start_or_end_date ) {
        start_or_end_date = 'start';
    }
// End date selected
    if ( start_or_end_date === 'end' ) {
        // Set min date to default
        picker.data( 'min_date', picker.data( 'o_min_date' ) );
        // Set fields
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_year' ).val( parsed_date[0] );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_month' ).val( parsed_date[1] );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_day' ).val( parsed_date[2] ).change();
        // Calc duration
        if ( picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            wc_bookings_date_picker.calc_duration( picker );
        }
        // Next click will be start date
        picker.data( 'start_or_end_date', 'start' );
        if ( picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            form.find( '.wc_bookings_field_start_date legend span.label' ).text( 'always_visible' !== picker.data( 'display' ) ? booking_form_params.i18n_dates : booking_form_params.i18n_start_date );
        }
        if ( 'always_visible' !== picker.data( 'display' ) ) {
            $( this ).hide();
        }
        // Start date selected
    } else {
        // Set min date to today
        if ( picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            picker.data( 'o_min_date', picker.data( 'min_date' ) )
            picker.data( 'min_date', date )
        }
        // Set fields
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_year' ).val( '' );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_month' ).val( '' );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_to_date_day' ).val( '' );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_date_year' ).val( parsed_date[0] );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_date_month' ).val( parsed_date[1] );
        fieldset.find( 'input.booking_date_day' ).val( parsed_date[2] ).change();
        // Calc duration
        if ( picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            wc_bookings_date_picker.calc_duration( picker );
        }
        // Next click will be end date
        picker.data( 'start_or_end_date', 'end' );
        if ( picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            form.find( '.wc_bookings_field_start_date legend span.label' ).text( booking_form_params.i18n_end_date );
        }
        if ( 'always_visible' !== picker.data( 'display' ) && ! picker.data( 'is_range_picker_enabled' ) ) {
            $( this ).hide();
        }
    }
    form.find( '.wc-bookings-booking-form' ).triggerHandler( 'date-selected', date, start_or_end_date );
```

Comment: what if the user selects some some wrong end date by mistake?

Comment: they still can change this, this is why a hardcoded solution of always disable message after 2 clicks is not what i am looking for.